# UiRouter scrolling to previous page location before route changes

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my application I have a list of search results.  When I click on a result I'm brought to a page with details of that search result.  When I go back (via back button on browser) either the browser or uiRouter picks up the scroll position of the search results page, which is what I want.  However, it scrolls to that position before it leaves the current page.   So on the details page if I click back the browser scrolls before the transition occurs.  Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: which version of angular are you using

Comment: I'm using angular 5

Comment: check this: https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/introduce-router-scroller-in-angular-v6-1-ef34278461e9

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using jquery or javascript 
this might help
window.scrollTo(0,0);

Comment: I don't want it to scroll on the details page though. I want it to stay where it is (which it doesn't do) then scroll when it goes back to the results page (which it does)